# Android - JavascriptInterface return JSONOnject to javascript

Tags: javascript, android, json

I use a JavaScript function to obtain data from JavaScript interface, like `var data = Android.getJsonData()`, and my java code looks like below:

```
public JSONObject getJsonData(){
    return AnotherClass.getData();
}
```

but I try to get the json object in JavaScript using `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` show me `{}`
however if I using `Log.e("",AnotherClass.getData().toString())` can successfully log the data
how can I return the json object to javascript?